# A bound on $I(X;Y)$ in terms of $I(X;Z)$ for $Y$ and $Z$ that are similar

Tags: probability, information-theory

Let $X,Y,Z$ be three random variables. Assume that $Y$ and $Z$ are binary. $I(A;B)$ is the mutual information between the random variables $A$ and $B$. I'm curious if there is a bound on $I(X;Y)$ in terms of $I(X;Z)$ and the probability of $Y=Z$, where the bound equals $I(X;Y)$ for $Y=Z$ with probability $1$.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to establish the following triangle-like inequality:
$$H(A|B) \le H(A|C) + H(C|B),$$
which is true for all jointly  distributed $A, B, C$. Indeed, due to chain rule we have:
$$H(A|B) \le H(A, C|B) = H(A|C, B) + H(C|B) \le H(A|C) + H(C|B).$$

Now, due to Fano's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano%27s_inequality since $Y$ and $Z$ are binary we have:
$$H(Y|Z), H(Z|Y) \le h(\Pr[Y\neq Z]),$$
where $h(x) = x\log_2(1/x) + (1 - x)\log_2(1/(1 - x))$ is a binary entropy.

Now notice that
$$I(X:Y) - I(X:Z) = H(X|Z) - H(X|Y) \le H(Y|Z) \le h(\Pr[Y\neq Z]),$$
$$I(X:Z) - I(X:Y) = H(X|Y) - H(X|Z) \le H(Z|Y) \le h(\Pr[Y\neq Z]),$$
that is 
$$|I(X:Y) - I(X:Z)| \le h(\Pr[Y\neq Z]),$$
and the latter tends to $0$ as $\Pr[Y\neq Z] \to 0$.